# Setting select options value/id in angularjs to work with ajax/php insert

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I am displaying a drop down select like this

```
<select name="ch" id="ch" ng-model="selected" ng-options="option.title for option in options" class="form-control3"></select>
```

This displays a set of options declared in my controller like so:

```
 $scope.options = [
        {
            title: 'P4',
            value: 'P4',
            id: 'ch',
            urlPrefix: 'http://test1.com/'
        }, {
            title: 'X1',
            value: 'x1',
            id: 'ch',
            urlPrefix: 'http://test2.com/'
        }];
            $scope.selected = $scope.options[1];
```

Now when inserting into my database previous to switching to this functionality it worked fine(before it was a select with id and then options with a value="") and the value would be inserted into the DB. Now it is not inserting the value instead I am getting a 0 or 1 depending on p4, or x1 selected. I tried adding name: 'ch', id: 'ch', value: 'ch' but it still inserted 0 for p4 and 1 for x1 into the database.
So my question is how would I go about selecting the value from each of the ngs drop down options that can be retrieved by my php script like so:

```
$ch = $_POST['ch'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in the `value` attribute set on the option.

> it worked fine(before it was a select with id and then options with a value="")

The browser will send the text value in, if there is no value attribute set, but if there is a proper value attribute set, it will submit the value.

e.g.

```
<select name="foo">
  <option></option>
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option value="">Kiwi</option>
  <option value="75">Pear</option>
</select>
```

If the user picks "Apple" or "Kiwi" that's what you will see on the URL... `foo=Apple` or `foo=Kiwi` but if they pick "Pear" you'll get `foo=75` (the value attribute)

To best control what you get, I'd be sure to set the value attributes to what you want for each option.

Comment: I had it working like you mention but I need to display the options like my first example and they are retrieved from my controller but the option is only inheriting the title: and urlPrefix: from the controller option, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I switched from using ng-options / select to ng-repeat / option which gave me the results I was looking for (insert to database works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Using this type of ng-options it will generate the options based on index. To fix this issue and to correct send the value to server you need to use a hidden element. Here is the code

```
<input type="hidden" name="ch" value="{{selected}}" />
<select id="ch" ng-model="selected" ng-options="option.title for option in options" class="form-control3"></select>
```

Now it will send the correct value to server. For more information for different types of ng-options check
https://github.com/farazshuja/ng-options/blob/master/README.md